# Spring Integration and http inbound adapter, how do I extract a principal user?

Tags: spring-security, spring-integration

Here's a controller I'm trying to replace:

```
@RequestMapping("/user")
public @ResponseBody UserRsp callUserService(Principal principal) {
    String authenticatedUsername = principal.getName();
    return userService.getUser(authenticatedUsername);
}
```

I'd like to replace it with an int-http:inbound-gateway that's mapped to a service adapter. I can't find any documentation on this, but what I'd like to do is something like this:

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway
 request-channel="requests" 
reply-channel="replies" 
path="/user" 
view-name="/user" 
payload-expression="#payload.principal.name"
supported-methods="GET"/>
```

But payload.principal is something I made up. Any ideas on the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Spring Security, something like this should work...

```
payload-expression="T(org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder).context.authentication.principal"
```

Comment: Excellent! I see that feature now in the SPeL docs, and it makes sense. It turns out that returns a org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User object instead of a java.security.Principal, but I can call .username on that and achieve the same result.

Comment: By the way, the principal (if present), is always mapped to a header...


 Message<?> message = messageBuilder
  .setHeader(org.springframework.integration.http.HttpHeaders.REQUEST_URL, request.getURI().toString())
  .setHeader(org.springframework.integration.http.HttpHeaders.REQUEST_METHOD, request.getMethod().toString())
  .setHeader(org.springframework.integration.http.HttpHeaders.USER_PRINCIPAL, servletRequest.getUserPrincipal())
  .build();