# Extracting a Principal User in Spring Integration HTTP Inbound adapter

Tags: spring-integration

In my Spring Integration project (with Spring Security API using Basic Authorization), I am trying to access the Principal object in order to read the Username.

This is the structure of the inbound gateway:

```html
<int-http:inbound-gateway request-channel="gatewayRequests"
  reply-channel="gatewayResponses"
  supported-methods="POST"
  path="/api/v1/myservice"
  request-payload-type="java.lang.String" reply-timeout="100">

  <int-http:request-mapping consumes="application/xml" produces="application/xml"/>
  <int-http:header name="principal" expression="T(org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder).context.authentication.principal"/>
 </int-http:inbound-gateway>
```

I got the aforementioned expression from the reply in this:
[Spring Integration and http inbound adapter, how do I extract a principal user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461436/spring-integration-and-http-inbound-adapter-how-do-i-extract-a-principal-user)

Despite successful authentication, I don't see the principal - is my syntax correct in expecting the result of the expression to be mapped to a message header?

Instead of the mapping to the header, if I were to use the following, how do I access the Principal value in the code layer (assuming it gets added into the payload)?

```html
<payload- 
 expression="T(org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder).
context.authentication.principal">
```

Can anyone kindly help me?

Sincerely,
Bharath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a header like:

```
.setHeader(org.springframework.integration.http.HttpHeaders.USER_PRINCIPAL,
                        servletRequest.getUserPrincipal())
```

in the message sent to the `gatewayRequests`.

Why that doesn't work for you?

OTOH that expression must work too. If you don't have that one, then you can't assume that you are authenticated correctly...

Comment: Inside the ServiceActivator listening to "gatewayRequests", I tried 2 approaches: Approach 1: Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(); String callerUserName = authentication.getName();  Approach 2: Principal principal = (Principal) incomingMessage.getHeaders().get("USER_PRINCIPAL"); String callerUserName = principal.getName();  Among these, Approach 1 worked but Approach 2 did not. This means the user got authenticated but not sure why the USER_PRINCIPAL doesn't contain anything.

Comment: That's not `USER_PRINCIPAL` literal. That's `.HttpHeaders.USER_PRINCIPAL` constant. Well, you definitely can check all the headers you have in the message. Just log it, for example

Comment: Perfect! Upon your advice, I logged all the headers and saw that the value "http_userPrincipal" was available and that this is also the value for the HttpHeaders.USER_PRINCIPAL constant.